# Hibernate ManyToOne using a ForeignKey to a non PrimaryKey target column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

User.java

```
private int userId;
@Column(name="status")
private String userStatus;

@ManyToOne
@JoinFormula(value="SELECT l.lookup_key FROM tb_lookup l WHERE l.category ='XXX'", referencedColumnName="status")
private Lookup statusLookup;
```

Lookup.java

```
private int lookupId;
@Column(name="category")
private String lookupCategory;
@Column(name="lookup_key")
private String lookupCode;
private String lookupDescription;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="lookupEntity", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<LookupDetail> lookupDetail;
```

LookupDetail.java

```
@Id
@Column(name="lookup_detail_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int lookupDetailId;
@Column(name="language_code")
private String languageCode;
@Column(name="lookup_val")
private String lookupValue;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="lookup_id", nullable=false)
private Lookup lookupEntity;
```

So basically i need to create many to one mapping annotation for user.java so it can provide sql query as such

```
select * from User u
inner join Lookup l in u.userStatus = l.lookupCode and l.lookupCategory = 'XXX'
```

please note that lookup_code is not primary_key (the primary key is lookup_id)
its a legacy database so i cant do much about it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `User` entity can have a `@ManyToOne` association to a non-primary key column:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="userStatus", referencedColumnName="lookupCode")
public Lookup getLookup() { return lookup; }
```

Now your query looks like this:

```
select u
from User u
inner join u.lookup l
where lookupCategory = :lookupCategory
```

---

If you want to include both conditions for that join, you'd have to use a `@JoinFormula`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinFormula(value="SELECT l.lookupCode FROM Lookup l WHERE l.lookupCategory ='XXX'", referencedColumnName="userStatus")
public Lookup getLookup() { return lookup; }
```

This uses a secondary SELECT, but since you use a legacy schema, you don't have too many other options.

Comment: thanks, it works but missing 1 more clause "and l.lookupCategory = 'XXX'"

Comment: sorry but its working since userStatus is User entity not the Lookup entity

Comment: sorry but its not working since userStatus is User entity not the Lookup entity

Comment: Indeed, I changed the Formula query. Try it now.

Comment: sorry its still not working. error : Unable to find column with logical name: userStatus in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(tb_lookup) and its related supertables and secondary tables  
it still referencing to the lookup table not the user table

Comment: The Formula uses an SQL query not a HQL, so you need to use the actual column names, if they differ from entity properties.

Comment: sorry it still didn't work. i adding some more info in the question, maybe helpfull. thanks in advance